# Login WebService PHP + SOAP + CURL + XML + certificado

Tags: php, web-service, xml, libcurl, soap

Boa tarde, estou com o seguinte código tentando acessar o webservice do ISS da prefeitura de Curitiba:

```php
<?php

$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ConsultarNfse xmlns="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/">
      <ConsultarNfseEnvio>
        <Prestador>
          <Cnpj>1312313123123</Cnpj>
          <InscricaoMunicipal>13123123</InscricaoMunicipal>
        </Prestador>
      </ConsultarNfseEnvio>
    </ConsultarNfse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>';

$url = "https://isscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br/Iss.NfseWebService/nfsews.asmx?WSDL";

$headers = array(
    "POST  /nfse_ws/nfsews.asmx HTTP/1.1",
    "Host: pilotoisscuritiba.curitiba.pr.gov.br",
    "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8",
    "SOAPAction: \"http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/ConsultarNfse\"",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml_data)
);

$xml = $xml_data;
$ch = curl_init();

$soapUser = "usuário_iss";  
$soapPassword = "senha_iss"; 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . '\Pref_ISS_Cert.pem');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $soapUser . ":" . $soapPassword); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSH_PRIVATE_KEYFILE, getcwd() . '\Pref_ISS_Cert.pfx');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, getcwd() . '\Pref_ISS_Cert.pem');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTPASSWD, "easy2017");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "$url");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$ch_result = curl_exec($ch);

print_r($ch_result);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Esse código não me permite fazer login site, consigo enviar o xml, mas não me da autorização para receber o xml de retorno, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> Erro do Servidor 403 - Proibido: acesso negado. Voc� n�o tem permiss�o para exibir esse diret�rio ou p�gina usando as credenciais
> fornecidas.

Contexto:

Gerei o certificado .pfx pelo site do ISS de testes, e vinculei o certificado a um usuário, até aí ok, criei o certificado .pem pois não estou conseguindo usar apenas o .pfx via linha de comando openSSL, duvida:

> 1 - Como fazer receber esse retorno com soap php enviando um xml usando
> certificado .pfx ?
>
> 2 - Existe outra maneira de fazer isso?